# Add an "hint" to my first simple python number guessing game

Tags: python, string, input, hint

I tried to make my first game on python.  There's something I don't understand because when I try enter "hint" has an answer, I get this error code:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:/Users/Lenovo/PycharmProjects/Test/while loop test.py", line 18, in <module>  
    if int(answer) == secret_number:  
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hint'
```

---

Can you give me any idea what i've done wrong? I tried to reassign the type string to the variable "answer" but it doesn't work.
Here's the code:

```
# Guessing game
import random
# Game explanation
print("Welcome to the Guessing game ! \nYou have 3 chances to find the number between 1 and 10, otherwise it ends!")

# Game variables
secret_number = random.randint(1, 11)
random_hint_number = random.randint(1, 5)
secret_number_hint = ("The secret number is between ", (secret_number - random_hint_number), (secret_number + random_hint_number))
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3

# game engine
while guess_count < guess_limit:
    answer = input("What is your guess?")
    guess_count += 1
    if int(answer) == secret_number:
        print("You won!")
        break
    elif answer == "hint":
        print(f"{secret_number_hint}")
        guess_count -= 1
    elif int(answer) != secret_number:
        print("Wrong answer")
        print("If you need an hint, type in: hint")
print("Sorry you failed")
```

Comment: For the input "hint", the conversion to an int will be tested before the comparison to the string hint. This causes an error when you try to parse "hint" as an int. You might want to reorder your conditions to perform the hint check first

Comment: Thank you ! I was going for a more complicated solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to test the input in the proper order

```
if answer == "hint":
    print(f"{secret_number_hint}")
    guess_count -= 1
    continue 

if int(answer) == secret_number:
    print("You won!")
    break
else:
    print("Wrong answer")
    print("If you need an hint, type in: hint")
```